# Dynamically adding Semantic UI modals with SilverStripe

Tags: modal-dialog, silverstripe, semantic-ui, dynamically-generated

I'm having a hard time trying to connect SUI modal with SilverStripe to generate them dynamically.

**I want to achieve something like this:**

I have button (attach events) to trigger modal with some content. I wanted to loop that elements (GridField) to generate everything dynamically. But the only thing I can achieve is multiple modals with the same "trigger class" and it doesn't matter which button I have clicked (first, last or whatever). I only have one modal (the last in hierarchy). Without SUI the solution is easy - put "this" to fetch the closest element and I can have as many different modals as I want, but SUI seems to complicate things.

I think the best solution will be to generate a class/id with SilverStripe and pass it to the JavaScript to use with modal or use one class for every modal and to "somehow inform" that this button triggers this modal.

Basically I need one code snippet to handle many modals, not many snippets to handle many modals. I hope it's clear enough what the the problem is.

Here is my code:

#### HTML/SS

(without specific SilverStripe tags)

```
<% loop SomeName %>
    <div class="job-offers">
        <a class="ui right floated button job-application">Click here</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ui basic modal job-application">
        <div class="job-application-sheet">        
            (...)                
            <div class="job-application-sheet-content">
                <div class="ui grid">
                    (...)
                    <div class="ui center aligned container job-application-action">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                        <button class="ui primary button">Click here</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.ui.basic.modal.job-application')
    .modal({
        autofocus : false,
        observeChanges: true
    })
    .modal('attach events', '.job-application', 'show');
```

As you can see "job-application" class is a trigger for modal, so is this possible to change it to "(this)" so I don't have to write "specific" class for each button/modal. Or maybe there is a different/easier solution?

Comment: I'm through the same situation, did you get to solve that ?

Comment: Hello Sebastian, nope sorry, no solution yet still waiting for response.

Comment: i solved this, let me show you on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i generated a data-type attribute for each of my elements that are going to display a modal when they are clicked, and in send as a local the same index to the modal this way:

```
    <% @relateds_array.each.with_index do |related,i| %>


        <div class="card custom" data-id="<%=i%>">
            <%= render partial: 'my_modal', locals: {index: i} %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

the i put the modal in the partial that i called my_modal for this example and used the index that i sent as a local to create an unique id for each my modals, like this:

```
<div class="ui modal" id="modal-<%=index%>">
  <p>blabla things inside this modal.</p>
</div>
```

and then with javascript, simply get the data-id of the element clicked and select the element that contain the id for that data-id, like this:

```
$('.element_that_you_want_to_open_moda_on_click').click(function(event){
    var card_clicked = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('#modal-' + card_clicked).modal('show');
});
```

Hope this was useful for you.
Note that i used Ruby on Rails for this example, but the behaviour that you should use should be something similar to this, no matter what framework you use.

Comment: Sebastian, you are my hero :) Thanks for your time and great insight. Under your soultion I'll provide snippets to use it without Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on [Sebastian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4389250/sebastian-delgado) solution. I did some minor tweaks to meet my needs, like I've used ID variable to automatically get DataObject ID which is generated dynamically.

**Basically to dynamically add Semantic UI (SUI) modal in SilverStripe, first you should add "data-id" in a modal trigger, for example:**

*Template.ss*

```
<a class="ui button custom-trigger" data-id="my-item-$ID">Click here</a>
```

then inside modal container add an "id" tag, for example:

```
<div id="modal-my-item-$ID" class="ui basic modal">
(...)
</div>
```

**Finally in JavaScript file:**

```
$('.custom-trigger').click(function(event){
    var triggerItem = $(this).attr('data-id');   

    $('#modal-' + triggerItem).modal('show');
});
```

I meet problem with SUI autofocus, so after a modal opens, screen went to the bottom and button placed there was highlighted.

**I tweaked original snippet adding SUI settings:**

```
$('.custom-trigger').click(function(event){
    var triggerItem = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('.ui.modal')
    .modal({
      autofocus: false,
      observeChanges: true
    })

    $('#modal-' + triggerItem).modal('show');
});
```

If someone wants to write "data-id trigger" manually using fields in CMS, then change $ID to $SomeField variable. Then normally add that field in .php file and in Page Controller add something like this:

```
public function init() {
parent::init();

Requirements::javascriptTemplate($this->ThemeDir().'/js/script.js', array(
'SomeField' => $this->SomeField

));
}
```

Hope this helps someone.